# WPF Stacked bar chart using WPF Toolkit

Tags: c#, wpf, charts

I am fairly new to both C# and WPF however i did come across the WPF toolkit which allows you to create chart fairly easily.

My goal is to create a stacked barchart however i am unable to find it in the kit the last question about this topic was asked in mid 2012 and i was wondering if anyone knows of any solution to creation of stacked bar charts using WPF?

Comment: This should help: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/04/16/the-one-with-all-the-goofy-heading-names-detailed-information-about-the-silverlight-toolkit-s-new-stacked-series-support.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Seems to be that the latest published version of the WPF Toolkit is 3.5 or 3.5.5, depending on where you get it from.

The stacked charts are only available in version 4 of the toolkit, which is available for Silverlight, but not officially for WPF.

If you'll head to [<s>this post</s>](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/04/22/nobody-likes-a-show-off-today-s-datavisualizationdemos-release-includes-new-demos-showing-off-stacked-series-behavior.aspx) (link seems broken due to MS archiving, i believe this was the [original post](https://dlaa.me/blog/post/10000936)), you can download the examples he uses ([direct link](http://dlaa.me/Samples/DataVisualizationDemos/DataVisualizationDemos.zip)).

Now, here's the beauty: browse to the "Toolkit -> WPF4" folder, and take the dll you'll find there. **This is the version 4 toolkit for WPF**, which you can then reference in your project, and have access to the stacked barcharts.

Side note: This toolkit is seriously lacking in documentation, and I'm not sure if it'll be updated in the future ... which is a shame.

---

**Update:** 7 Years later, it would seem you can try this one out: [Extended WPF Toolkit](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit) . I haven't tried it, but it might be useful to whomever walks this path in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It's too late but anyway I put it here for fellows like me:

> The WPF Toolkit hasn't released a new version since the April 2010
>   Silverlight Toolkit was released with stacked series support, so
>   what's in the current download is not the latest stuff. However, you
>   can get the latest version of the Data Visualization assembly
>   (binaries and code) for all supported platforms as part of my
>   **Development Release**: [download](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/04/20/phone-y-charts-silverlight-wpf-data-visualization-development-release-4-and-windows-phone-7-charting-sample.aspx)

From here:http://dlaa.me/blog/post/9997400#comment-1378418769