# Stacked bar chart WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, charts

I am trying to get a stacked bar chart but apprently its harder than it looks.

I have been reading this blog:  [MSDN BLOG](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/04/16/the-one-with-all-the-goofy-heading-names-detailed-information-about-the-silverlight-toolkit-s-new-stacked-series-support.aspx)

But the documentation of how to actually get it to work is lacking ALOT!

I have also been looking at other stacked bar chart but since me and my company is using Windows XP i am restricted to .Net 4.0 which means that i apprently can only use the offical WPF toolkit.

Now my question is simple, does anyone know any stacked bar charts **OR** have experiance  with the above mentioned blog ?

Comment: Try this https://github.com/ailon/amCharts-Quick-Charts

Comment: @Jodha does this contain a stacked bar chart?

Answer (score 1):

As you said, the documentation is lacking (ALOT indeed).

It seems that stacked bars aren't really officially released either, since you need to a bit of a hack to get the version 4 of the toolkit in order to get them (see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17022367/wpf-stacked-bar-chart-using-wpf-toolkit/19416803#19416803))

Having said that, I got them up and working.
So my answer to the second one is: Yes :).

Answer (score 1):

You can try to download a trial version of [LightningChart](http://arction.com/), the fastest and fully configurable Charting and Data visualization components for .Net. Examples are included in download package. You also can read about benchmark and see for yourself.

It uses .Net4 framework.